# what is the actual resolution of an iphone screen

Tags: css, iphone, screen-resolution

I'm developing webpages to be viewd on Iphone. To get exact resolutions on iPhone 
I tested following lines of code.

```
    pageWidth = $j(document).innerWidth();
    alert(pageWidth);
```

according to 
http://www.iphoneresolution.com/ my Iphone 5 has 640px width,

But when I execute my code I get following alert.

this image is from Simulator, I get the same on my Iphone
[image: iphone screen pixels are less then what it is described]

Can somebody please tell me what is this so?.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`screen.width` will give you the width of the device's screen.

You'll also want to note that the device's resolution does not correspond with the resolution the webpage displays in.

See http://www.mydevice.io/devices/

Comment: should i follow screenwidth or innerwidth in html development? because contents (div, li, img etc) are positioned absolute by x and y positions.

Comment: Since HTML uses `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right` for positioning, I'd say the `screen.width` and `screen.height` would only be useful for `bottom` and `right` positioning. X and Y would refer to `left` and `top` respectively and therefore I can't see any benefit using `screen.width` or `screen.height` in that case. For example, in the case of using `right` and `bottom` I could see `screen.width` and `screen.height` used to ensure that an element does not go off the screen.

Comment: Thanks .. mydevices.io/devices/ is really a helpful resource.